# Destroying game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, gameobject

I have created a simple 2D touch game in Unity and I have spikes spawning at the top of the scene every 3 seconds and when the spikes fall the player will tap the spikes before they hit the characters below, however, when I test the game, when I tap the spike (game object) it destroys all of the spikes (game objects) in the scene. Here is the code:

```
public GameObject spike;
public float spawnTime1 = 1f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("SpawnSpike", spawnTime1, spawnTime1);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}

void SpawnSpike () {

    var newSpike = GameObject.Instantiate (spike); 
    newSpike.transform.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-3, 3), 11f, 0f);
```

Comment: Maybe you game objects are nested, and you destroy their "parent"? Could you show us the hierarchy?

Comment: Is this script some kind of distinct "game-manager"? If so, that's good.
But in your `Update()`, how are you calculating what `gameObject` is?

Comment: @d4Rk. Yeah sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2asmjn4muv5tw0/Screen%20Shot%202016-01-27%20at%2018.40.38.png?dl=0

Comment: @andeart In the'Update()'  I have my touch function and when the player touches the scene it counts how many touches are pressed and destroys the 'gameObject' which is the spike (sprite). 

Comment: Seems ok so far.. I think you need to share more code.. Where is this code located? Is it a MonoBehaviour? But then you would destroy itself with `Destroy (gameObject);` So probably not..

Comment: @JohnGool I have a feeling that you imagine the `GetTouch` term means that the object is touched- that is not so. The `GetTouch` returns a value if any part of the screen is touched, not just this script's object. Please excuse me if you knew that already.

Comment: @andeart Thanks. I did not know that. I thought that GetTouch meant that once the screen is touched the script attached the gameObject in my case destroyed. What code or function would I use to destroy a single gameObject? Thanks for you help btw 

Comment: @JohnGool I've added some extra code in my answer to help you get going. Beyond that, I **strongly** recommend researching or going through tutorials so you get the hang of some common mechanics in Unity programming. Good luck!

Comment: You say this script is `C#` but the line `var newSpike = GameObject.Instantiate (spike); ` should be `GameObject newSpike = GameObject.Instantiate(spike) as GameObject;` and the `for loop` condition should be `for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're destroying this game-manager-like script itself when you run

```
void Update () {
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The line `Destroy (gameObject);` is destroying its own game-object, which I'm guessing is parented to the spikes that are instantiated(?); hence destroying all the spikes at once.

I suggest using raycasts to find out if any spike is tapped on and/or which spike is tapped on, and then destroying only the game-object of that spike. Here's a good [reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html). I also suggest looking for tutorials regarding the same if you're still finding it hard to understand.

I hope that helps!

**UPDATE**:

Here's some sample code to get you going:

```
    if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(pos, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit != null && hit.gameObject.CompareTag("spike") && hit.collider != null) {
            Debug.Log ("I'm tapping "+hit.gameObject.name);
            Destroy(hit.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

This specific code would require that your spike prefab (template) has the tag "spike". I also suggest you place this code in some kind of a global "game-manager" script's `Update()` (rather than in the Spike script), so that you don't over-process the touches.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really appreciate it! 

Comment: @JohnGool Glad I could help. Good luck!